# Pattern to reduce code in a Spring Boot configuration class

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration, javabeans

I have a trouble with a big @Configuration class(It's responsibility is to set up rabbitmq). I want to apply any pattern that can solve my issue but I did not find an appropriate info. What you guys Do when your @Configuration class becomes huge? Is there any pattern I can use?

Comment: This question is very broad. Could you show you configuration class, or indicate what you find problematic about it? In general, when things become to big you need to split them up...

Comment: I didn't get your real problem but if you are talking about  class with many beans, you can create many class configuration has many beans and share bean among them.

Comment: Yes I have too many beans in my configuration class and I want to find out how to get things better

Comment: Welcome on SO ! Please [edit] your question to make a [mre]